# I would like to know how to view rolled back objects?

Tags: sql-server

I created ddl trigger for `create table` and in that trigger I also did a rollback. Now how can I view  the table that tried to be created?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't.

Once the creation of the table has been rolled back, the table does not exist in the database anymore.

You will need to remove the rollback from the trigger, let the trigger create the table, review the table and then rollback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logging to check the tables that tried to be created, before rollback.
Handle the exception, if any exception occurs, log the details and rollback.

Comment: If you log within the same transaction any logging will be roll backed too

Answer (score 0):

You can log it into a table from trigger after rollback.
Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AuditDDLEvents
(
  id               INT      NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  posttime         DATETIME  ,
  eventtype        sysname  ,
  loginname        sysname  ,
  schemaname       sysname  ,
  objectname       sysname  ,
  CONSTRAINT PK_AuditDDLEvents PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
go

CREATE TRIGGER [trg_create_tbl] ON DATABASE FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @eventdata AS XML = eventdata();


ROLLBACK

INSERT INTO dbo.AuditDDLEvents(
  posttime, eventtype, loginname, schemaname, objectname)
  VALUES( @eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]',         'VARCHAR(23)'),
          @eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]',        'sysname'),
          @eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]',        'sysname'),
          @eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',       'sysname'),          
          @eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',       'sysname')
          );
```

Now try to create a table and it will end up in the trigger but doing

```
select *
from dbo.AuditDDLEvents;
```

you'll get all the info about who, when, and what was the table name

Comment: Create trigger trigname on database for create_table

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. First you say you've created the ddl trigger that does rollback and you want to know what was the table created. Now you say that what is not working is "Create trigger trigname on database for create_table ". So what does not work? Your trigger?

Comment: Create trigger trigname on database for create_table as begin rollback; end. Then I tried to create table tblstudent it didn't get created bcoz trigger rolled it back. Now i want to see table which was rolled back.  U seem to be helping I love u

Comment: @Imtiyaz Ahmad bhat you are right, when it's rolled back from ddl trigger it cannot be found in the default trace, I did my test creating a table within a transaction finishing it with rollback and it was catched. I'll update my answer if I find how to track it, if no, I'll remove my answer

Comment: @Imtiyaz Ahmad bhat, I've updated my answer with the code